# Issue on upload image in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multipartform-data, multer

Req.file and req.files comes out to be undefined.

I have tried using the methods people have found useful but none worked for me.

```
var upload = multer({dest: './public/files/lost/'});

//INDEX - show all items
router.get("/", function(req, res){
   res.render("items/report");               
});

//CREATE - add new lost to DB
router.post("/", upload.single("image"), function(req, res){
    // get data from form and add to items array
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.files);
    // Other req.body usage here
})
```

Form

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 style="text-align: center">Report for the Lost Item</h1>
        <div style="width: 30%; margin: 25px auto;">
            <form action="/report" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="type" placeholder="request type">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="date" placeholder="date">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="time" placeholder="time">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="location" placeholder="location">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="phone">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="image" placeholder="image url">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" placeholder="description">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit!</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="/report">Go Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<% include ../partials/footerstudent %>
```

I expect req.file to contain the filename and other attributes of the file uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I observed you are submitting the form to **report** endpoint. it should be consume in this way

```
router.post("/report", upload.single("image"), function(req, res){
    // get data from form and add to items array
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.files);
    // Other req.body usage here
})
```

But to reassemble the uploaded file in your application, you'll need to parse the request body (as multipart form data).

In **Express 3.x** you could use `express.bodyParser` middleware to handle multipart forms but as of **Express 4.x**, there's no body parser bundled with the framework. 
There are many packages available Assuming that you are using **mutler and Express 4.0**

First make sure that API is consuming right by sending other params